# How does STRICT_ALL_TABLES work with multi-row statements and partial updates?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

In the docs for [`STRICT_ALL_TABLES` it states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html),

> For `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, MySQL returns an error and ignores the rest of the rows. **However, because the earlier rows have been inserted or updated, the result is a partial update. To avoid this, use single-row statements, which can be aborted without changing the table.**

What does this mean though?

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a int NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL), (NULL);
```

This does what everyone would reasonably expect a totally insane database to do,

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 0 |
| 0 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, I expected a multi-row `INSERT` to insert the non-violating rows that are seen first,

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (5), (NULL);
```

To insert **just** one row with `5`, as per the docs in `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`. Instead it does,

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'a' cannot be null

How do I interpret the docs to `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` when they say *earlier rows .. partial update* and *"single-row statements"*. And why is MySQL doing something less horrible then documented? I'm pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the split between `_ALL_` and `_TRANS_` needs clarification.

Earlier on that page it says

> With TRADITIONAL mode enabled, an INSERT or UPDATE aborts as soon as an error occurs. If you are using a nontransactional storage engine, this may not be what you want because data changes made prior to the error may not be rolled back, resulting in a “partially done” update.

I think the meat of the issue is InnoDB versus MyISAM.

MyISAM is covered by `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, but not by `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`.  If an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` is aborted for any reason mid-stream, some rows will have been updated or deleted.  You have no practical way to clean up the mess.  (This is a major reason never to use MyISAM.)

InnoDB is covered by both settings, but `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is more relevant, and overrides the statement about "earlier rows".  `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are atomic.

Also involved is the question of aborting with an error versus doing something so you can keep going.  For example, bad dates and defaults without an explicit `DEFAULT`, etc.  These are cases where MySQL (unlike some other engines) defines that a non-abort action will be taken.

If your Question is intended to point out poor phrasing in the documentation, go for it.  But do it at bugs.mysql.com , where there is a chance of it getting fixed.

MySQL 8.0 moves toward more robust default settings by changing the defaults.